# Getting 403 when trying to push packages to nuget.org

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I've been following this document on [How to Publish a Package to nuget.org](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/publish-a-package) gallery, and I keep getting 403 forbidden.

I've done the following steps:

1. Browsed to my account in nuget.org.
2. Clicked on my name -> API Keys
3. Created an API key as such:
   [image]
4. I already have a .nupkg file, so now I try:

```
$ nuget.exe push .\Test.1.2.3.nupkg -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -Apikey <apikey>
```

And I keep getting:

```
Pushing Test.1.2.3.nupkg to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'...
  PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
  Forbidden https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 2238ms
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (The specified API key is invalid, has expired, or does not have permission to access the specified package.).
```

Why is that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message said "The specified API key is invalid, has expired, or does not have permission to access the specified package."

You can check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-the-dotnet-cli#publish-errors)

> If you're using a valid API key that you just created, then this message indicates a naming conflict, which isn't entirely clear from the "permission" part of the error. Change the package identifier, rebuild the project, recreate the .nupkg file, and retry the push command.

Hope it can solve yout problem.

Comment: @JinamiagoXu-MSFT - the paragraph you copied just say that you need to copy the API key once you generate it, because you won't be able to do it later. Rather - you'll need to regenerate it.

Comment: @YoavKlein Maybe you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-the-dotnet-cli#publish-errors): If you're using a valid API key that you just created, then this message indicates a naming conflict, which isn't entirely clear from the "permission" part of the error. Change the package identifier, rebuild the project, recreate the .nupkg file, and retry the push command.

Comment: you are right. package name conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, this is how I resolved this issue, I've tried this for DotNet Framework

Once you build your project using `nuget spec` a `Nuspec` file is generated, try to keep the Nuspec file name as Unique, you can open the `Nuspec` file and edit it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anr33.png)

Generate a Nuget package using `nuget pack <project-name>.nuspec`, this will generate the Nuget package (**Note**: Nuget package name will be generated based on the ID that is available inside the Nuspec file)

Now you can push the Nuget package using `dotnet nuget push <nuget package name> --api-key <api-key> --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Answer (score 0):

Go the Tool-->Nuget Package Manager-->Package manager setting-->go to the package source and delete all the existing package source.

click on Plus button on right top corner and add latest Api key in source and click on update button.
you can easily get the Api key on below url:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview

This is worked for me.